# Chrome Javascript Date AM | PM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to get this format:

```
2:18:00 pm
```

Using the sample code from w3Schools.com below, I can get the correct results from IE and FireFox. **But when it comes to Chrome,** I get the 24hr clock version where it is simply displayed this way:

```
14:18:00
```

In FF

```
    new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    //   2:18:00 pm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following javascript code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();
if (curr_hour < 12)
   {
   a_p = "AM";
   }
else
   {
   a_p = "PM";
 }

document.write(curr_hour + ":" + curr_min + ":" 
+ curr_sec+ a_p);

</script>
```

The o/p would be as you expect,`2:18:00 PM`

Comment: This returns 14:18:00 PM for me. I think you meant to subtract 12 hours if it's PM?

Comment: @Eli, a better solution is: var curr_hour = d.getHours() % 12;

Comment: @Fydo, won't that return 0 hours for noon?

Answer (score 2):

```
function twoDigitPad(number) { 
    return ("0" + number).slice(-2);
}

function twelveHourTimeString() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var min = twoDigitPad(date.getMinutes());
    var sec = twoDigitPad(date.getSeconds());
    var ampm = hour < 12 ? "am" : "pm";
    hour = hour % 12 || 12;  // convert to 12-hour format
    return hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + ampm;
}
```

[`date.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) returns an integer between 0 and 23, which `hour % 12 || 12` converts to the 12-hour format.

`date.getMinutes()` and `date.getSeconds()` each return an integer, so you'll need to zero-pad those values when they're less than 10. Optionally, `hour` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with dates reliably cross-browser is a ball-ache in javascript- I would use the DateFormat library; http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

then as he notes on the page, you can call it like so;
dateFormat(now, "h:MM:ss TT");

There are a few alternatives, but this one seems the most light-weight.

Comment: Sorry, But i cannot use external. else we have so many options